# Binding data to WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have creating following GridRow as UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Telematics_Plugin.GridRow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" BorderBrush="LightBlue"
             MaxHeight="30" MinWidth="900">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            <TextBox Width="60" Text="{Binding EventId}"/>
            <TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding MethodName}" />
            <ComboBox  Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding }" />
            <ComboBox Width="200"/>
            <ComboBox Width="200"/> 
            <Button Click="OnClickEdit">
                <Image Source="Images/edit.png"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="OnClickDelete">
                <Image Source="Images/delete.png"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the code behind

```
public partial class GridRow : UserControl
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Opcode { get; set; }
        public string Task { get;set; }
        public string Keyword { get; set; }

        public GridRow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void OnClickEdit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OnClickDelete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now can you please tell what important thing I missed to bind properties of code behind files to UI in TwoWay Mode..

Although this is not the MVVM way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `x:Name` to your control and bind to the properties using `ElementName`:

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyGridRow">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyGridRow}" />
            <TextBox Width="60" Text="{Binding EventId, ElementName=MyGridRow}"/>
            <TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding MethodName, ElementName=MyGridRow}" />
            <ComboBox  Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., ElementName=MyGridRow}" />
            <ComboBox Width="200"/>
            <ComboBox Width="200"/> 
            <Button Click="OnClickEdit">
                <Image Source="Images/edit.png"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="OnClickDelete">
                <Image Source="Images/delete.png"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to support updating the values, you should use `DependencyProperties` instead of normal properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(GridRow));

public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
    set { GetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Added an example `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: value is still not reflecting on UI, I think something small is missing in above code

Comment: That's odd, could you share the instantiation of your control, where you set the properties? Oh and I forgot to mention that `DependencyProperty` should be `readonly`, but that ought not cause the issue in case you were using them.

Comment: BTW what is the best way to bind ComboBox type of controls which have multiple values..

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean and it sounds like a new question. Try searching SO and in case you cannot find it, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

when the **DataContext** where you use your usercontrol has all the properties IsChecked, EventId,MethodName ,..., then  you can remove the properties from your usercontrol and all works.

but if you wanna create a "real" usercontrol then you should use DependencyProperties and bind them with the right expression within your usercontrol.

btw when you use Binding in WPF then its all about the right **DataContext** and the right **BindingExpression**